# Decomposing certain elements in ${_2\pi_*^s}$

Tags: at.algebraic-topology

At the prime $p=2$, for specific values of $i,j>0$, Lin has constructed certain elements in ${_2\pi_{2^{i+1}+2^{j+1}}^s}$ that are detected by $h_2(h_{i+1}h_j^2+h_i^2h_{j+1})$ in the Adams spectral sequence. For $r=2^i+2^j$, such an element is constructed as a composition of maps 
$$S^{2r}\longrightarrow\Sigma^rB(r/2)\longrightarrow S^0$$
where $B(n)$ is the $n$-th Brown-Gitler spectrum. We know that when $n$ is an odd number, $B(n)$ is realised as a space after finite number of suspensions. I do not know of anything like this for the case of $n$ being even. What I am interested in is either

(i) a factorisation of the map on left, i.e. $S^r\to B(r/2)$, through suspension spectrum of a finite stable complex, i.e. suspension spectrum of a (de)suspension of a space.

(ii) a factorisation of the map on right, i.e. $\Sigma^rB(r/2)\to S^0$, through suspension spectrum of a finite stable complex, i.e. suspension spectrum of a (de)suspension of a space.

(iii) another construction of the map $S^{2r}\to S^0$ above that does factorise through suspension spectrum of a finite stable complex. Note that if we remove the condition of being a finite complex, then we have the Kahn-Priddy theorem.

If such a construction exists, then I will appreciate any reference to it.

Thanks!

**Edit** I later on realised that the spectra $B(r)$ can be obtained from Snaith splitting for $\Omega^2S^3$. But, I was not sure if this is for the prime $p=2$. Now, I have found references to this in papers of Ralph Cohen, as well as papers of Fred Cohen, Don Davis, Paul Goerss and Mark Mahowald. 
Still, any comment on any of the above questions would be very helpful.

Comment: After your edit it's a bit hard to see at once where the question starts... maybe the additional text would rather fit at the end?

Comment: @YCor Just moved it to the end!